# Using template language in Django in a DRY way

Tags: django, django-templates

I've troubles using Django template language in a DRY way.

I defined base-section.html, which is a base for all sections of my website.
Each section must override some pieces of code in this basic template to provide proper title, icon, description, body of the section, etc - always in same way.

Now, I want to write some code in each section, but I don't like the idea of overriding about 10 blocks in each section, because it would be writing same things again and again.

Whereas keyword for specified section is X:

- title of the section is X, too
- title of the website in a browser is X, too
- name of icon is X+"_icon.png"
- and so on

I'll appreciate a solution where I can assign only 1 or 2 variables per section and have my templates working.

Is it possible?

Comment: You could have `{{page_title}}` from the views

Answer (score 0):

A lot of this data could simply be passed along with the view. However, I often find that writing a custom template tag might be preferable.

You could take a look at custom tags in the Django documentation: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-template-tags/

Using either a simple tag or an inclusion tag, you can quite easily reuse template code.